# C# Override try-catch in another function

Tags: c#, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I am using a dll that I got from the internet for utilizing a webcam in C#.  If it can't find a webcam connected I would like to display something like "Unable to find a camera to use.  Please verify that no other applications are using your camera at this time and try again".  The problem I am having is the creator of the dll included a try-catch in their dll programming...so my try-catch never see's the exception because a "object referenced not set to an instance of an object" error comes up instead (formatted by a try/catch into a MessageBox).  Is there a way I can override the built-in error handling before it displays the message and display my own?

Comment: Figure out how they are testing for a WebCam first, then call their method... unless you want to figure out how to automate a debugger.  ;-)

Comment: Billy, where did you get that DLL?  Mom, I got it from the Internet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting "object referenced not set to an instance of an object" (`NullReferenceException`), then it is likely they didn't actually catch the exception.

If you want to catch that exact case (and let others errors you don't know about and can't handle fall through - the proper way to do exception handling), you can try getting down and dirty with the stack information included with the exception:

```
class Program
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        string blah = null;
        Console.WriteLine(blah.Length);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            string methodName = e.TargetSite.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(methodName);

            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace =
                new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true);

            int lineNumber = trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
            Console.WriteLine(lineNumber);

            if(methodName == "DoSomething" && lineNumber == 13)
            {
                ShowErrorToUser(); // Todo: Implement this
            }
            else
            {
                throw; // Just re-throw the error if you don't know where it came from
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Found out in the comments that it really is being caught, and displayed in a message box.

I will leave this answer since it is applicable to a similar situation, but not applicable to this situation.  See OscarMK's answer instead.

Comment: I tried catching a NullReferenceException specifically but I still get the same thing.  I am not sure if I was clear or not about it before but it is coming up in a messagebox, so I know he is using a catch to display any error that happens in his code.  I need to somehow override that and have no idea how since by the the my try/catch is able to handle it, his already has.  It is not life and death but I want a bit nicer error message that someone might actually be able to understand.

Comment: @Brandon: Nope, it wasn't clear :)  Can you edit your question to make "object reference ... comes up instead" say something about that error being displayed in a message box?  Also, if there is no issue with code licensing, you could try using something like ILSpy to rip the code out of the DLL.

Comment: Will do, I didn't know about that program I will have to check it out.  It is a "open source" project as it is posted that way on different open source sites, except he didn't post his code.  He just posted his C# project files source code.

Comment: @Brandon: Just letting you know to be careful.  BTW, that program can crack open MS assemblies, too, which is quite helpful when MSDN/other documentation lets you down :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

I found the offending code:

// WebCam_Capture.WebCamCapture
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       …
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while capturing the video image. The video capture will now be terminated.\r\n\n" + ex.get_Message());
        this.Stop();
    }
}

Timer1 has a private scope, how can I override the _Tick method without totally recreating his dll?

Comment: Never mind, I found http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1 and it completely decompiled it back to a vs project....that is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the try-catch block only, but you could override the method and basically do everything the previous method is doing and removing the try-catch block.

Comment: I would love to but I don't know how to handle a camera, that is why I went out looking for a solution.  I tried using WIA but it seems to habe a lot of issues and the dll I found was made to do exactly what I needed.  (I hope that didn't sound snarky because it wasn't intended to be)

Comment: I would suggest using a disassembly tool like ILSpy to see how their code works so you can write a better version.